# origin = 'lower' has no effect in Imagegrid

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is the example, the testOrigin() works, 2nd axes flipped the image. The testGridOrigin() however always show flipped images or non-flipped images in all axes. Can anyone tell my why it behaves like this? Any way to fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
from matplotlib import colors
def testOrigin():
    x = np.arange(100.0); x.shape = 10,10

    interp = 'bilinear';
    plt.subplot(211, axisbg='g')
    plt.title('blue should be up')
    plt.imshow(x, origin='upper', interpolation=interp)

    plt.subplot(212, axisbg='y')
    plt.title('blue should be down')
    plt.imshow(x, origin='lower', interpolation=interp)
    plt.show()


def testGridOrigin():
    fig = plt.figure()
    grid2 = ImageGrid(fig, 111,
                  nrows_ncols = (1, 2),
                  direction="row",
                  axes_pad = 0.05,
                  add_all=True,
                  label_mode = "1",
                  share_all = True,
                  cbar_location="right",
                  cbar_mode="single",
                  cbar_size="10%",
                  cbar_pad=0.05,
                  )
    x = np.arange(100.0); x.shape = 10,10

    interp = 'bilinear';
    for ax, _orig in zip(grid2, ['upper', 'lower']):
        print _orig
        ax.imshow(x, origin = _orig, interpolation=interp)
    plt.show()
```

here is the version

```
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.3.1'
```

update:

I tried on 1.4.3. It has the same problem.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @atomh33ls I think he wants to know why `testGridOrigin()` shows a flipped image